# How can I capture STDERR into bash variable and not affect STDOUT?

Tags: bash, pg-dump

I'm trying to capture the error from `pg_dump` and cannot figure out how to get it into a bash variable. This does not work because STDOUT is going to gzip.

```
OUTPUT=$(/bin/pg_dump -c --if-exists --dbname=cfMaster -U cfMaster | /bin/gzip > ~cftvdun/dbbackups/cfMaster.tmp.sql.gz)
```

How can I get STDERR into a bash variable in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$( )` construct always captures stdout, but you can juggle between file descriptors. Just group the pipeline in `{ }`, and then redirect the stderr of the group to standard output with `2>&1`:

```
output=$( { /bin/pg_dump -c --if-exists --dbname=cfMaster -U cfMaster | /bin/gzip > ~cftvdun/dbbackups/cfMaster.tmp.sql.gz; } 2>&1 )
```

If you also wanted the standard output (rather than just sending it to a file), it'd get more complicated. I think in that case you'd have to juggle through FD #3.

BTW, I'd also recommend using lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names to avoid accidental conflicts with the variables with special meaning to the shell or other utilities.

Comment: That did it! I don't know what "FD #3" is but that's OK. :)

Comment: @TimDuncklee FD = file descriptor. stdin is FD #0, stdout is FD #1, stderr is FD #2. FD #3 can sometimes be used as a spare. But you don't need it in this case, so don't worry about it. :)

Comment: @Gorgon Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand. :)